# How do i get rid of the network folder shortcut?

Tags: google-drive

I connected my google account when installing, and there is a shortcut to open the drive files. Now when deleting this account, this shortcut is this here, but I find no way to remove it.

Comment: you haven't provided any details of your ubuntu release, but in general (on ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04) go to `settings > Online Accounts` and deselect Google from there.

Comment: I don't know why I removed it three times and it wouldn't be effective.
I had to to it three time, maybe after a system update.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (and interim releases) go to `settings > Online Accounts` and deselect `Google` from there.